# Collating data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in SQL Server

```
St    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
===========================================
603   2    5    1.5  3    0    0    0    0
603   0    0    0    0    2    1    3    5
```

As I insert the data by batches, each batch only has 4 columns each and I want to collate the data to the following

```
St    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
===========================================
603   2    5    1.5  3    2    1    3    5
```

but most of the threads I see here are about concatenating strings of a single column.

Anyone has any idea on how to collate or even merge different rows into a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the group by and Sum key word of the t-SQL

```
      SELECT SUM(COL1) , SUM(COL2)..... FROM tbl GROUP BY ST
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GROUP BY` clause and aggregate with `SUM` fields 1-8 :

```
SELECT St, SUM(1), SUM(2),.. FROM tbl GROUP BY St
```

Comment: I am going to accept Devesh's answer cause not only is his faster by a spilt second in answering but his syntax is more correct. Thanks for answering though +1